# Could there exist some subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi$ is algebraic over that subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Could there exist a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi$ is algebraic of, say degree 5 over $F$?

We know that $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is not a field. right?

So, could there exist some other subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi$ is algebraic over that subfield?

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is not a field?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} / ker$. Note that $\pi$ is transcendental, hence the kernel is zero, not a maximal ideal, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is not a field

Comment: The kernel of what is zero?

Comment: Sorry, the kernel of the evaluation homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$

Comment: If $\phi$ is the evaluation homomorphism, the first isomorphism theorem says the the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\ker{\phi}$ is isomoprhic to the image of $\phi$. Are you sure $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is the image of $\phi$?

Comment: yes, since you are just plugging in $\pi$ to every $x$ in $Q[x]$

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$ is not a field for the exact reason you said, but $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is certainly a field by definition.

Answer (score 7):

The symbol $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ is a field by definition. It is the smallest field inside $\mathbb R$ that contains all of $\mathbb Q$ and also $\pi$. More concretely, you can think of it as all rational expressions $\frac{f(\pi)}{g(\pi)}$ where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials in one variable with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ and $g$ is not the zero polynomial. We can be sure that the bottom is never zero for any choice of $g$ because $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb Q$. So the inverse of $\frac{f(\pi)}{g(\pi)}$ is given by $\frac{g(\pi)}{f(\pi)}$ and you can see that it is a field.

The element $\pi$ is algebraic of degree $5$ over $\mathbb Q(\pi^5)$, just like an indeterminate $x$ is algebraic of degree $5$ over $\mathbb Q(x^5)$. As far as $\mathbb Q$ is concerned, it "understands" $\pi$ as little as it understands $x$. In it's mind, both satisfy no polynomial relations involving $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: is $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^5)$ a field?

Comment: Yes, that’s a field. As Ravi says in his answer, it’s the smallest field inside $\Bbb R$ that contains $\Bbb Q$ and $\pi^5$. You may construct it, by the way, as the intersection of all subfields of $\Bbb R$ that contain $\Bbb Q$ and $\pi^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, consider the field $\mathbb{Q}[\pi^2]$, the subfield generated by $\pi^2$, it does not contain $\pi$ since $\pi$ is trancendental, $\pi$ is the solution of $X^2-\pi$.

Comment: You probably meant to write $\mathbb Q(\pi^2)$ instead of $\mathbb Q[\pi^2]$ since the latter is not a field.

Answer (score 1):

By Eisenstein's criterion $X^5-\pi^5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[\pi^5][X]$.

By Gauss's Lemma, $X^5-\pi^5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q(\pi^5)[X]$.

This implies that $\pi$ is algebraic of degree $5$ over $\mathbb Q(\pi^5)$.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain the implications. I am familiar with Eisenstein for $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, but never seen it applied to something like $\mathbf{Q}[\pi^5][X]$.

Comment: @MaxisJaisi - See the Generalized criterion in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalized_criterion) 
Wikipedia sub-entry. Note that the ideal of $\mathbb Q[\pi^5]$ generated by $\pi^5$ is prime. (Indeed, $\pi$ being transcendental over $\mathbb Q$, so is $\pi^5$, and thus $\mathbb Q[\pi^5]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[Y]$, where $Y$ is an indeterminate.)

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted.